# Flink Timestamp monotony violated

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm consuming data using a Kafka Consumer 0.9 and after some initial filtering for valid events and mapping to POJO I am setting AscendingTimestampExtractor.

using Joda Time library I'm returning the milliseconds since epoch as follows:
`return DateTime.parse(evnt.timestamp).getMillis();`

This seems to result in 
`WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.timestamps.AscendingTimestampExtractor  - Timestamp monotony violated: 1478048406982 < 1478051502295`

Of course the ordering is different but what I don't understand is how make sure these are in order? Should I be ordering these based on this timestamp and then performing any keyBy or timeWindow?

I haven't really found much information on this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `evnt.timestamp` look like? If you're going through time zone conversion, that could well be the issue. (Those timestamps look like they are indeed just either side of a DST transition.)

Comment: Are the elements in your Kafka partition monotonic wrt `evnt.timestamp`?

Comment: `evnt.timestamp` is ISO 8601 formatted in UTC. example: `2016-11-02T01:51:11.363Z`

Comment: I meet same problem. Do you solved it?@AtharvaI

Comment: I did not. I haven't used Flink since I posted the question. Not able to help.